# Laravel POST routes sending as GET route when deployed on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When running in development, all routes work as intended. However, once running through aws POST routes seem to run as GET routes, and therefore do not work.

```html
<form method="post" action="{{route('logout')}}">
  @csrf

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-right-from-bracket fs-4"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

A simple logout route like this works in development but produces a MethodNotAllowedException (The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.)

[Method Not Allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80CH3.png)

This has a web route created using Laravel Breeze:

```php
Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->name('logout');
```

Comment: can you share link?

Comment: unfortunately not, as this contains exposed company data throughout development

Comment: Add controller maybe will show more information also do php artisan optimize:clear